# RabbitMQ: Message Queue loses its Consumers

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a Message Queue which loses its Consumers from time to time.

[image]

What could be the possible reasons for this? And how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the possible reasons for this?

The most obvious reason is your client application stopping or crashing. Without more information, it is impossible to answer this question.